# Why do child objects don't follow the parent's rigging

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, parent, pose-mode

I have created a sphere on top of a cube as follows:

[image]

And have set the sphere to be a child of the cube:

[image]

Then I added an armature to bend the square like this:

[image]
[image]

The thing is, since I set the sphere to be a child of the square, I have expected that from now, when I bend the square using the armature,  the square would follow it. But it doesn't:

[image]

How can I set the sphere so it would follow the direction of any bending I do to the square?

Comment: Use Object > Keep Transform rather than just Object on the Parenting menu.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: Do yu want the sphere to follow the centre of the face? If so I guess you'd have to add a vertex in the centre of the face by Joining the verts at the opposite corners and then subdividing the edge that's created. Then read up on Parenting in the Blender Manual. I guess you'd need [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html#vertex-parent-from-edit-mode) section although I've never used it.

Comment: i had exactly this problem literally now with my face rig where the eye balls got left behind despite parented to the face. my solution was to select the eye balls and then select the armature and go into pose mode. then shift click the bone and press `ctrl+p`  > with automatic weights. so in your case its the ball parented to a bone in pose mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the Sphere then <kbd>Shift</kbd> click the armature
- Go into *Pose* mode and <kbd>Shift</kbd> click the top bone
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> *> With Automatic Weights*

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work when I tried it because the sphere doesn't follow the face of the cube as the bone moves. Mind you, your answer has been accepted so presumably it worked for @Eule.

Comment: i attached a gif for better understanding :)

Comment: Hmm. Ok. I believe you! :^)  I've deleted my test file now so can't check what I did wrong...